# Missing method exception with Hololens 2 and Microsoft.MixedReality.QR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to scan QR codes with Hololens 2 by creating a unity project, building the unity project and then deploying the solution that unity generates.

I've tried following this guide: https://localjoost.github.io/Reading-QR-codes-with-an-MRTK2-Extension-Service/

Whenever any of the code runs for Microsoft.MixedReality.QR runs, I get a missing method exception for System.RuntimeType::GetGUID(System.Type, System.Byte[])

The exception happens even if I just check whether scanning for QR codes is supported with the following line:

```
QRCodeWatcher.IsSupported();
```

The stack trace looks a bit like this:

```
System.Reflection.TragetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException:
System.RuntimeType::GetGUID(System.Type, System.Byte[])
    at System.RuntimeType.get_GUID() [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000>:0
    at WinRT.IObjectReference.As[T]()[0x00000] in <00000000000000000000>:0
    at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1[T].As[I]() [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000>:0
    at Microsoft.MixedReality.QR.QRCodeWatcher+Statics..ctor()[0x000000] in <00000000000000000000>:0
```

If it helps, I'm using Windows SDK 10.0.19041.0 and Unity 2021.2.3f1

Answer (score 0):

No idea about hololens, but...

I've seen this many times due to there being different versions of the assemblies being used/expected.

Some higher level code it trying to find a method via reflection, but the installed assembly (at least the one being discovered) is of a version that does not have that method.
(this will always be a problem with reflection based "binding").

So, check that all the versions are compatible.

If you've recently upgraded some part, it's possible that VS/msbuild has left some old version lying around. (It "caches" dll's under the obj folders as a build optimisation. But sometime trips up over recognising that something needs updating).

In powershell, try `ls -include obj,bin -recurse | rm -recurse -force` from the root of your solution folder.
This will delete all "bin" and "obj" folders under your solution. Then rebuild.

It's a big ugly stick but
This has often worked for me in these situations.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It's a recently created project so I feel like it would be unlikely but I'll give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for this scenario.

Comment: was worth a try.
might be worth checking that your project is targeting the right runtime etc
GetGuid is way down in the c++ layer and seems to be implemented differently for different environments.
At this point I run out of talent... good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have cloned the sample provided by the guide; it works fine(with Unity2019.4.33f1). I noticed this guide sets the project XR pipelines as Legacy XR, and Legacy XR is deprecated in Unity 2019 and removed in Unity 2020, you should roll back your Unity to 2019 LTS: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases?version=2019.4

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used to have horrible flickering issues with earlier version of unity (very similar to [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-app-flickering-using-hololens-2.1196794/)) so I'm hesitant to downgrade, but if all else fails, I'll give it a go.

Comment: For your information, the flickering issue in Unity2020.3.21 and later has been fixed in 2020.3.24f1 LTS patch update, see https://forum.unity.com/threads/flickering-issue-affecting-hololens-2-projects-in-2020-3-21-and-later.1200199/